# Beep by PhoneGap- Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, notifications

I tried to use the PhoneGap notification and beeping when a function is called (Android)

According to [**this**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.beep) document

All I have to do is put this line:

```
 navigator.notification.beep(2);
```

And add in app/res/xml/plugins.xml this line:

```
<plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
```

and in app/AndroidManifest.xml this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

It did not work for me.

My function:

```
function BeepNow() {    
    navigator.notification.beep(2);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I was missing the **JS of cordova** in head